# Pronounce the word "Buddh" - phonetics

Tags: the-buddha, terminology, pali-language

What is the phonetic of the word "Buddh" spoken in time 21:47 to 21:48 minutes of [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=avEmbY83RO0). I am a novice in phonetics.

The phonetic of the word Buddha is wriiten as 
[bud̪ːʱə] in [this wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha)

However, to my taste, the english prononciation of the B and U in the word Buddh does not matches exactly with that of the video.

Let me know how to phonetically write the word "Buddh" spoken in time 21:47 to 21:48 minutes of the video.

Comment: Which language are you asking about: Pali?

Comment: I think that i wrongly tagged pali language. I meant phonetics in english. I need the phonetics in english  of the word pronounced in hindi.

Comment: @changzhao I think mathstudent means using the latin alphabet as it is pronounced in English to represent the sound of the Hindi word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is tagged with "**Pali** language". Pronunciation in Wikipedia is written probably for **Sanskrit**. The movie is in **Hindi**. And **English** is another language. Pronunciation in different languages is different. For example, in **Russian** we pronounce Bood-dah.

When we study phonetics, we need to understand, phonetics of which language or dialect we study.

---

PS:

**I meant phonetics in english. I need the phonetics in english of the word pronounced in hindi.**

@MathStudent, the phonetics in English is of English words. The word pronounced in Hindi is Hindi word. Do you want phonetics of English word "Buddha" or of Hindi word "Buddha"?

Anyway, see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Buddha

> Pronunciation:
>
> - (UK) enPR: bo͝odə, IPA(key): /bʊdə/
> - (US) enPR: bo͞odə, IPA(key): /buːdə/
> - IPA(key): /bʊdːʰə/ (only in technical contexts) – approximation of Hindustani [ˈbʊdːʱə], which features a geminate ‘d’ and breathy voice on the second ‘d’, neither of which is idiomatic to English

That reference gives three different English pronounciations: one English; one American; and a "technical" one that's meant to sound a bit like Hindustani.

Comment: I meant phonetics in english. I need the phonetics in english  of the word pronounced in hindi.

Answer (score 1):

B-month&month&stronger touch+soft breathe out+voice louder.
U-put,push,fruit.
D-teeth&tongue tip&stronger touch+soft breathe out+voice louder.
DH-teeth&tongue tip&stronger touch+soft breathe out+voice louder.
A-cut,watt,shut,but.

See:padarupasiddhi for more information.